# Octave script run through Netbeans 8.2 (Java Project) is not creating files (edit: not running at all)

Tags: java, bash, netbeans, octave, netbeans-8

I ran an Octave script through Java's ProcessBuilder and Process classes. I used Netbeans and the Script file is in resources folder of the Project I am doing.

When run from bash directly the script is working fine. When run from Java, I'm pretty sure the script is working fine.

In the below program,

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf
function ret = manipulateCell(x)

    x = x/max(x(:));
    x = x.*255;
    x = int32(x);
    a1 = mean(x(:));

    ret = a1<70;
end

img = imread('aaa.png');
imgInd = rgb2ind(img);
imgGray = ind2gray(imgInd,colormap());

sizeVector = 100*ones(1,20);


Cells =  mat2cell(imgGray,sizeVector,sizeVector);

ManipCells = cellfun(@manipulateCell,Cells);

file2D = fopen('data.txt','rw+');
dlmwrite(file2D,ManipCells);
```

Last two lines seem not to run from Netbeans; there is no output (i.e., no output file is created).

Java Code which is used to run this script.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("src/resources/ProcessImg.m");
try{
    Process p = pb.start();
}
catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

--
Edit:

I have just tried `imshow(img)` in between the above code. It didn't work either.

---

Edit:

How I verified that ProcessBuilder and Process work fine? and How do I know which directory I am in.

```
String command = "pwd";
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(command);
        //pb.directory(new File("./"));

        try{
        Process p = pb.start();

        //Debug Code
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

        String s;

        while((s=bf.readLine())!=null){
            System.out.println(s);
        }

        p.getInputStream().close();
        p.getOutputStream().close();
        p.getErrorStream().close();
        }
        catch(IOException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

If the `command` string is `pwd`, the output is

```
/home/user/NetBeansProjects/Project
```

If the `command` string is `ls`, the output is

```
build
build.xml
manifest.mf
nbproject
src
test
```

I want to say that commands are being executed.

Also, process builder is identifying shebang notation.

---

The problem is NetBeans is not allowing ProcessImg.m to create files in it's directory by an external process probably.

---

```
#!/usr/bin/octave -qf
function ret = manipulateCell(x)

    x = x/max(x(:));
    x = x.*255;
    x = int32(x);
    a1 = mean(x(:));

    ret = a1<70;
end

img = imread('~/Desktop/aaa.png');

imgInd = rgb2ind(img);
imgGray = ind2gray(imgInd,colormap());

sizeVector = 100*ones(1,20);


Cells =  mat2cell(imgGray,sizeVector,sizeVector);

ManipCells = cellfun(@manipulateCell,Cells);

file2D = fopen('~/Desktop/data.txt','rw+');
dlmwrite(file2D,ManipCells);
```

I have put absolute path (from home) as suggested and it didn't work. Not only in NetBeans did the file hasn't been created but also on desktop.

Comment: please provide a complete MCVE. From the code above you are, for example, missing fclose...

Comment: Have you tried specifying a *full file path* rather than simply `data.txt`?

Comment: @Andy I have not provided fclose but running the script from bash is giving me the output.

Comment: @Suever Since, the script worked directly from bash. Is it really the problem?

Comment: Well you should change it to a full file path to test to ensure that the file is actually being written. I suspect your current directory isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @Suever I have update how I verified path. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that "ProcessBuilder" doesn't understand the Shebang in your script (or you haven't set it executable) and you have to call it like

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/usr/bin/octave",
                                       "src/resources/ProcessImg.m");
```

But this looks like a common problem so I suggest searching for "ProcessBuilder execute bash script" (or perl script) which gives many hits.

Also try an absolute path to your script and explicitely close your file on exit.

Comment: I have tested it outside netbeans by manually running the ProcessBuilder and Process. I didn't change the code or permissions. It worked fine.